# Page with 5k nested Vuejs components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have page with 5k nested vuejs components.
It is "comments", with a tree-like structure.

Component's template is something like this `comment-item.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- some text -->
     
    <comment-item v-for="child in children" :key="child.id" :data="child">
  </div>
</template>
```

In some cases, I need to show all of them without hiding. And after reaching 1-2k of them, the page is frozen completely, especially on mobile browsers.

How I can optimize render and CPU/memory consumption?
Also, I need SSR support for search robots, but in this case, I can show fewer comments.

Comment: Use virtual scrolling. What use case is there to display 2K comments at once?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vue-virtual-scroll-list` for this thing. Using this `vue` component you can support a big amount of data list with high scroll performance.

One more thing you can choose among the various modes in it like `vfor-mode`, `item-mode`, `variable height` etc.

Hope this solves your problem.

[image]

You can read its documentation [here](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-vue-component-support-big-amount-data-list-with-high-scroll-performance/)

Comment: Thanks. Does it supports SSR?

Comment: Maybe yes! if this answer what you want to know then please accept it as answer